# Converting or re-writing CRC-32 code in Processing programing language

Tags: c++, c, processing

I am using a piece of code in C++ and compiling it in Arduino IDE to calculate CRC-32 bytes of an array of bytes. I am not sure how anyone is familiar with Processing programing language, but I really appreciate your help to help me re-write or convert this piece of code for compiling in Processing. As far as I am aware Processing is a Java based language and I am not that experienced in it.

Moreover, I find Processing not really flexible in term of memory allocation to variables, particularly when you have ‘unsigned’ variables. As you can see there are also cases in the CRC code where I need to use ‘unsigned’ variables which I believe allocates four bytes of memory to them.
I really appreciate any help and guidance as I have been stuck on this for a good while now.

```
/*
The block of code that calculates the CRC-32 starts here
*/

static PROGMEM prog_uint32_t crc_table[16] = {
0x00000000, 0x1db71064, 0x3b6e20c8, 0x26d930ac,
0x76dc4190, 0x6b6b51f4, 0x4db26158, 0x5005713c,
0xedb88320, 0xf00f9344, 0xd6d6a3e8, 0xcb61b38c,
0x9b64c2b0, 0x86d3d2d4, 0xa00ae278, 0xbdbdf21c
};

unsigned long crc_update(unsigned long crc, byte data)
{
byte tbl_idx;
tbl_idx = crc ^ (data >> (0 * 4));
crc = pgm_read_dword_near(crc_table + (tbl_idx & 0x0f)) ^ (crc >> 4);
tbl_idx = crc ^ (data >> (1 * 4));
crc = pgm_read_dword_near(crc_table + (tbl_idx & 0x0f)) ^ (crc >> 4);
return crc;
}

unsigned long crc_string( unsigned char *s, unsigned int length)
{
unsigned long crc = ~0L;
unsigned int i;
for(i = 0; i<length;i++){
crc = crc_update(crc, *s++);
}
crc = ~crc;
return crc;
}

/*
The end of CRC-32 block
*/
```

Comment: Since Processing is kind of a simplified Java, why not simply look for a CRC32 example in Java that you can port instead (if you can't find existing code for Processing directly)?

Comment: Good idea. I believe I am upto something with CRC, but any ideas on allocating four bytes of memory and interpreting them as 'unsigned'? This one is not for CRC. In my program which I complied in Arduino IDE, I had a 'unsigned long' variable to store four bytes of data. I know that the integer in java and Processing is four bytes, but it is signed.'unsigned' does not work in Processing. Nonetheless, any ideas whether I can get something like a "unsigned long" variable in Java?

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out. Thanks for your help

Comment: Rather than using `unsigned long`, use `uint32_t`.  This is important as `unsigned long` could be more than 32-bit and would create issues with `(crc >> 4)`.

Comment: I see. I know based on the documentation that 'unsigned long' allocates 32-bits (or 4 bytes) to the variable in the Arduino microcontroller board that I am using. Nonetheless, thanks for the heads up.